# How to declare optparse.Values type as global

Tags: python

I'd like to set 'options' as global:

```
(options, _) = parser.parse_args()
```

What's type is it ?.

TIA,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't need to be explicitly initialized with a specific type of value.  You just need to use the `global` keyword:

```
global options
(options, _) = parser.parse_args()
```